# Moving a large number of files in one directory to multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to create a Windows batch script to move about 2,000 files and splitting them up so that there are 10 files per folder.  I have attempted creating a batch script but the syntax really boggles my mind.  Here is what I have so far

```
@echo off

:: Config parameters
set /a groupsize = 10
:: initial counter, everytime counter is 1, we create new folder
set /a n = 1
:: folder counter
set /a nf = 1

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
:: if counter is 1, create new folder
if %n% == 1 (
    md folder%nf%
    set /a n += 1
)

:: move file into folder
mv -Y %%f folder%nf%\%%f

:: reset counter if larger than group size
if %n% == %groupsize% (
    set /a n = 1
) else (
    set /a n += 1
)
)
pause
```

Basically what this script does is loop through each .txt file in the directory. It creates a new directory in the beginning and moves 10 files into that directory, then creates a new folder again and moves another 10 files into that directory, and so on.  However, I'm having problems where the `n` variable is not being incremented in the loop? I'm sure there's other errors too since the CMD window closes on me even with `pause`. Any help or guidance is appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: @Brian: Show me a version of Windows that comes with Python or Perl installed ... other languages are fine, but there are many valid reasons to still use batch files. Besides, above code isn't that complicated. I've seen (and written) worse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things you need to know:

- `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is needed, since you are changing variables and using their changed values in a single parenthesized block. `SET /?` on the command line will give some info. Search the internet for this term and you will find a better explanation.
- The places I use the `!nf!` format for variables is related to delayed expansion.
- As ghostdog74 mentioned, you weren't incrementing `%nf%`.
- I initialized `nf` to 0 instead of 1. This way, the folder number you want to move files to is the same as the folder number you just created. In your code, you create folderX, then increment X, and then try to move the file to X+1.
- You have to use `MOVE` to move a file, `MV` is not valid.

This batch file works...but make sure you test! I only tested on a small amount of files.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Config parameters
SET groupsize=10
:: initial counter, everytime counter is 1, we create new folder
SET n=1
:: folder counter
SET nf=0

FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
  :: if counter is 1, create new folder
  IF !n!==1 (
    SET /A nf+=1
    MD folder!nf!
  )

  :: move file into folder
  MOVE /Y "%%f" folder!nf!

  :: reset counter if larger than group size
  IF !n!==!groupsize! (
    SET n=1
  ) ELSE (
    SET /A n+=1
  )
)

ENDLOCAL

PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Johannes. I oversimplified when I said ENABLEDELAYEDEXANSION was need for the math to work. That's not true. But, you do need it to access the value as it changes.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at this tomorrow before I accept this answer :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a ton @aphoria

Answer (score 0):

you are not incrementing `%nf%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file (referred to here as "x.bat") which has the links to the folders that you want to put the files in:

```
mkdir "FilesToHere\1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\Example 1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\4"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example3"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example 1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\6"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\7"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\7\Example 1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\7\Example6\1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\7\Example6\1\Example7"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example5\7\Example7"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example4\5\Example 1"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\2\Example2\3\Example8"
mkdir "FilesToHere\1\Example9"
```

2000 files/20 folders = 100 files/folder. (You can changed the numbers in the following for your own files/folder preference. "[...]" indicates that, for example, 16 list items are missing in a list expressed as "1, 2, 3, [...] 20". Directory "s" has the 2,000 files. "FilesToHere" is located in "C:\user\Documents\ex1\ex 2\".) You can distributed the files in this way:

1. Open "cmd.exe" and run

```
cd C:\user\Documents\FI\le\s
dir/b>../temp.txt
```

2. Run "C:\user\Documents\FI\le\t.bat", which contains

```
cd C:\user\Documents\FI\le\s
powershell -command "& {Get-Content ../temp.txt -TotalCount 100}" > ../temp1.bat
gvim -c "execute \"normal! 100dd\"" -c "wq" ../temp.txt
powershell -command "& {Get-Content ../temp.txt -TotalCount 100}" > ../temp2.bat
gvim -c "execute \"normal! 100dd\"" -c "wq" ../temp.txt
powershell -command "& {Get-Content ../temp.txt -TotalCount 100}" > ../temp3.bat
gvim -c "execute \"normal! 100dd\"" -c "wq" ../temp.txt
[...]
powershell -command "& {Get-Content ../temp.txt -TotalCount 100}" > ../temp20.bat
gvim -c "execute \"normal! 100dd\"" -c "wq" ../temp.txt
```

3. Run the following with file "C:\user\Documents\FI\le\x.bat" opened in gvim (use http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/ if one or more of your filenames contain "```")

````
:%s/\\/\\\\/ge | %s/^mkdir "FilesToHere/gvim -c "%%s\/^\/move \\"\/g" -c "%%s\/$\/\\" \\"C:\\\\user\\\\Documents\\\\ex1\\\\ex 2\\\\FilesToHere/g | %s/"$/\\\\\\"\/g" -c "wq" ..\/temp```.bat/g | let i=1|g/```/s//\=i/|let i=i+1
````

4. Run "C:\user\Documents\FI\le\x.bat", which contains

```
cd C:\user\Documents\FI\le\s
gvim -c "%%s/^/move \"/g" -c "%%s/$/\" \"C:\\user\\Documents\\ex1\\ex 2\\FilesToHere\\1\\\"/g" -c "wq" ../temp1.bat
gvim -c "%%s/^/move \"/g" -c "%%s/$/\" \"C:\\user\\Documents\\ex1\\ex 2\\FilesToHere\\1\\Example 1\\\"/g" -c "wq" ../temp2.bat
gvim -c "%%s/^/move \"/g" -c "%%s/$/\" \"C:\\user\\Documents\\ex1\\ex 2\\FilesToHere\\1\\2\\\"/g" -c "wq" ../temp3.bat
[...]
gvim -c "%%s/^/move \"/g" -c "%%s/$/\" \"C:\\user\\Documents\\ex1\\ex 2\\FilesToHere\\1\\Example9\\\"/g" -c "wq" ../temp20.bat
```

5. Run "C:\user\Documents\FI\le\x.bat", which you changed to make contain

```
cd C:\user\Documents\FI\le\s\
call ..\temp1.bat
[...]
call ..\temp19.bat
call ..\temp20.bat
```

Note: If you get the error "'■t' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." (like I did, on Windows 10), then you have to convert whatever batch file(s) you are running from Unicode to ANSI. ( See also https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/problem-executing-cmd-files.209442/ )

I find this method to be very helpful if you are trying to move like 10,000 files into 100 folders (10,000/100=100 files/folder) and the 100 folders are spread out in a nonuniform way (e.g., the 100 folders are not all in one directory and the 100 folders have parent-child relationships with each other). Related links/text:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501086/cmd-move-the-first-n-files-from-current-directory-into-another-directory
- https://www.wikihow.com/Special:CreatePage?target=move+the+first+n+files+from+current+directory+into+another+directory+with+CMD - How to Move the First N Files from Current Directory Into Another Directory with CMD