# batch move script gives syntax error, doesn't move files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have [the following](https://superuser.com/questions/1442270/batch-script-to-move-x-number-of-files-to-empty-folders/1442317#1442317) script

which works well with files that have simple names.

But the files I need to use it on have the following name pattern:

(#.a#-##-##-##abcd-abcd-##abc_abcdef_a#-##-##)

basically a combination of letters, numbers,  one period, dashes, hyphens and one comma and no spaces

where you see the # symbol are numbers.

The starting numbers( #. ) are from 0-10000

 the file names are anywhere from 72 - 76 characters depending on their number id.
they are all of the same type ( but that wouldn't really matter script isn't extension specific)

it gives the error:

*The syntax of the command is incorrect.*

My guess is the issue is with the file names starting with a number or have a period in the name.

I cannot remove any of the characters, the file names themselves are part of the data as well.

I have tried using chcp 65001 at the top of the file, but it doesn't make a difference.

I am very new batch scripting and not sure how to bypass this issue. I have tried searching the error but it seems like a general error msg.

```
@echo off
set /a counter=1
set /a filesperfolder=100
cd dir\dir_main

:loopstart
set dirname=subdir%counter%
md %dirname%
echo %dirname%

dir /b | findstr /v /i "subdir*"> %temp%\temp.txt && for /l %%l in (1,1,%filesperfolder%) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^" %temp%\temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%%l:"') do @move %%b %dirname%\%%b >nul

set /a counter=%counter%+1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %temp%\temp.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set _filesmoved=%%a
del %temp%\temp.txt
IF %_filesmoved% LSS 100 goto done

goto loopstart

:done
cls
echo All files were moved!!
pause
exit
```

The issue is not with the quantity of files but the file names.
The script does not have issue with simple ( as in all letters) file names.

Comment: Your explanation and code is IMO extremely convoluted. If you want to move files in batches to subfolders there **are** examples here on SO.

Comment: In all probability, `%temp%` contains spaces, so you'd need to quote any occurrence of `%temp%`  eg use `"%temp%\temp.txt"` in place of `%temp%\temp.txt`. Why not simply use your `findstr/n` method and divide the line number by `filesperfolder` to determine the subdirectory-suffix? It'll require `delayedexpansion` but would make the code less complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving a large number of files in one directory to multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541887/moving-a-large-number-of-files-in-one-directory-to-multiple-directories)

Comment: @Compo that does not resolve the issue. As I stated, the issue is with the files names, not the quantity of files. I tried it with simple file names and there is no error

Comment: @Compo i've explained the file names, their format, number of characters, in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went in and removed different characters to see which specific combination is causing the issue. The issue is caused by the comma and the spaces within the file name.

Used this to remove the spaces and comma and replace with either dash or hyphen. The period, dash and hyphen do not cause the issue.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*, *) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:, =_!"
)
```

Also found a simpler moving script

```
@echo off
set SourceDir=%~dp0\SourceFolder
set TargetDir=%~dp0\Targetfolder
set MaxFiles=100
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B "%SourceDir%\*.*" ^|
find /v /n ""') do (
move "%SourceDir%\%%~nxH" "%TargetDir%\"
if %%G==%MaxFiles% exit /b 0)
```